# How to move TelephonyManager to different class then MainActivity

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager

im making and APP about the Network information etc.
I got a problem when i want to use TelephonyManager in different class then my MainActivity class. 
When i have a simple code in one class then everything is working OK, but the problem is when i want to make another class. Program then is compiling without any problem, but the APP is crashing.

Working code in one class:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView textMCC = findViewById(R.id.mcc);
    textMCC.setText(getMCC());
}
public String getMCC() {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String networkOperator = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperator();
    return networkOperator.substring(0, 3);
}
```

When i try to split this to two different classes, MainActivity.java and Cell.java the APP is crashing.

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


 Cell cellex = new Cell();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView textMCC = findViewById(R.id.mcc);
    textMCC.setText(cellex.getMCC());
}
}
```

Cell.java:

```
public class Cell {
Context context;
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

public String getMCC() {
    // TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String networkOperator = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperator();
    return networkOperator.substring(0, 3);
}
}
```

Before adding line: Context context, the program didn't compile.

Comment: You just added a variable, never initialized it, and tried to call a function on it. You may want to read about how variables work in Java - it's different than, say, C++.

Comment: I know, but when i want to start it without Context context, program is not compiling. 
Do you know maybe how to implement TelephonyManager object in other class then main class? Or maybe i need to make object in main class and then pass it through method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because Activity has method getSystemService which forwards the request to Context.getSystemService(). So you have to send param Context inside getMCC().

String getMCC(Context content){
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_MANAGER_SERVICE);
}

String mcc = cell.getMCC(MainActivity.this);

Comment: When i try to put this inside the method

 `   public String getMCC() {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
//rest of the method code
    }`

It gives me an error:
error: non-static method getSystemService(String) cannot be referenced from a static context
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

Comment: my mistake. getSystemService() is not a static method.. Please use my updated answer

Comment: Thanks mate! Apps stop crushing. I actually tried something similar, but my syntax must be wrong.